# Filament Group's loadCSS vs. ajax

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, performance

Filament Group's [loadCSS library](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS) seems to be the de-facto standard for loading CSS asynchronously. Even [Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/resource-prioritization#other_techniques_and_tools) suggests using the library. However, I was wondering why not just use ajax to load the CSS asynchronously. Something like this:

```
fetch('styles.css').then(response => {
  const el = document.createElement('style');
  el.textContent = response.text();
  document.head.append(el);
});
```

This would be a lot less code (a bit more with error handling or using XHR) but since I assume that the Filament Group guys are pretty smart people, I was wondering if I missed some obvious disadvantage of the ajax approach.

So what are the pro's and con's of loadCSS vs. the ajax approach?

Comment: They make a lot more than just a request. If preload is available loadCss tries to use it and other stuff explained here https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/async-css.html

Comment: Not in their pure JavaScript version: https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS/blob/v2.0.1/src/loadCSS.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found one issue myself: **Relative URLs won't work anymore**.

#### Explanation

Imagine a CSS file with a content like this:

```
.background {
    background-image: url("../images/background.jpg")
}
```

The file's URL is something like `/assets/css/background.css`, so the background image can be found under `/assets/images/background.jpg`. When I use ajax to load the CSS file and inline it using a style tag, I will get something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <style>
            .background {background-image: url("../images/background.jpg")}
        </style>
    </head>
...
</html>
```

Then the browser won't find the background image anymore, because the relative URL is still relative to the original location of the CSS file and not the current page.